# how to convert format time "hhmmss.ss" to "hh:mm:ss.ss" in python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have time in series, let's say 002959.20. I would like to change in this format 00:25:59.20 with timezone (+7.00) or 07:25:59. I have tried with 'strftime', but it's not working. How can i change the format? really appreciate any help! :)

**edit**
Here's my data:

```
$PU    003114.00
$PU    003114.20
$PU    003114.40
$PU    003114.60
$PU    003114.80
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

Here's my code:

```
y =  (New[Time])
import time
time.strftime(y,'%H:%M:%S.%f')

output:
TypeError: strftime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

and I tried to convert to string

```
TypeError: Tuple or struct_time argument required
```

Comment: You'll need to be more clear on why it isn't working.

Comment: first, TypeError: strftime() argument 1 must be str, not Series. I changed the object to str, but it came up with TypeError:Tuple or struct_time argument required. I tried to change it and it said "time format is not match". I do not know what's wrong in here, but is there anyway to change this format?

Comment: Can you post sample data

Comment: I just edit the question, please take a look @AndrewL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to `datetime` this way:

Using your data:

```
s
0    003114.00
1    003114.20
2    003114.80
Name: test, dtype: object

# reassign the Series to datetime format
s = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%H%M%S.%f')

s
0   1900-01-01 00:31:14.000
1   1900-01-01 00:31:14.200
2   1900-01-01 00:31:14.800
Name: test, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Adding 7 hours:

```
s = s + pd.offsets.Hour(7)
0   1900-01-01 07:31:14.000
1   1900-01-01 07:31:14.200
2   1900-01-01 07:31:14.800
Name: test, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: But I just only need the time, is it possible to remove the date?

Comment: `s = s.dt.time` will convert to time. Please accept as answer if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There most certanly is a better solution (this is literally the worst possible solution), but you could:

Add 70000 to your current time

Convert it to a string

and group them like this: string[0] string[1] : string[2] string[3] : string[4-8]

Comment: ah thanks, but i don't think it will be efficient when there a lot of million data points.

Comment: the rpbolem with cde like this i s more semantics than efficiency - this would be more efficient than parsing the points into  datetime objects and re-rendering them as strings - which is the correct thing to do anyway.